# How best to label inappropriate use of images

Tags: word-choice

I'm describing the downsides of publishing text on the web as a image file, instead of real text. For example:

- Images are inaccessible for users with visual disabilities (screen-readers need *something* to speak)
- Images are harder for services (like Google) to index and search for
- Images are near-impossible to process and extend with browser extensions and functionality (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, [user-chosen fonts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/opendyslexic/cdnapgfjopgaggbmfgbiinmmbdcglnam), etc.)

I have terms for each of these use-cases: "inaccessible," "machine-unreadable," and "inextensible." But I need to consolidate them into a single term (classification restraints).

I've considered "opaque," but describing images as opaque would more suggest lack of transparent pixels.

Comment: I guess it causes much *inconvenience*. Is that too general for your case?

Comment: Consider prefixing one of the following words with "cyber":  inflexible, inextensible, brittle.

Comment: @RexYuan I describe the practice elsewhere as unsuitable for smartphones and horrible for data plans, so you're right about the general shape of things, but I need a little bit more specific

Comment: To compensate there is the alt="explain image" image tag.

Comment: @Bookeater The images in this case require solutions more akin to `longdesc`

Comment: All of your examples makes the text ***unusable*** in some way.

Comment: @Jim That might be the word for me to look up synonyms for.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider ***[incompatible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incompatible)***.

> (Of two things) so different in nature as to be incapable of coexisting:
>   cleverness and femininity were seen as incompatible
>
> (Of equipment, computer programs, etc.) not capable of being used in combination:
>   all four prototype camcorders used special tapes and were incompatible with each other
>
> SYNONYMS
>   irreconcilable, conflicting, opposed, opposite, contradictory, antagonistic, antipathetic;
>   clashing, inharmonious, discordant;
>   mutually exclusive